# How come if this is a reserved word in javascript, i'm still able to set it as a property?

Tags: javascript

Well this time, there was some interesting behavior that i observed, i would defeinitely like to know more.

```
 var doStuff = function() {
  this.this = function() {
    console.log("I'm the other this"); 
  }

  this.this(); //Is this legal to be used ?

};


doStuff.call(null);
```

Output

> I'm the other this

Comment: My guess is that this is allowed because you can set object properties dynamically, e.g. `myObject[foo] = 123`. So if `this` weren't allowed to be a property then the variable `foo` could only contain values other than 'this', which would be limiting.

Comment: But of course your code example should definitely be avoided...

Comment: For the same reason that in C# you could have 
public class Foo {
private string class;
}

Or in MySQL you can do this 
SELECT * FROM `Database`.`Table`

You aren't attempting to use the reserved word in a way that creates ambiguity for the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'[The syntactic grammar defines Identifier as an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord (see 11.6.2)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords)' However [object properties can be accessed with `MemberExpression . IdentifierName`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors), and IdentifierNames aren't subject to that restriction.